# Display all months with posts and inside each month show the 5 latest posts

Tags: posts, archives

I need to display all the months that have active posts, and inside each month I need to display at least 5 posts that are tied to each month.. the HTML will look like this:

News items

```
<h6>May</h6>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Souvlaki ignitus carborundum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Defacto lingo est igpay atinlay</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quote meon an estimate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Souvlaki ignitus carborundum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Defacto lingo est igpay atinlay</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quote meon an estimate</a></li>
</ul>
<h6>April:</h6>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sic tempus fugit esperanto hiccup</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Epsum factorial non deposit</a></li>
</ul>
```

Not sure how I can go about this or what function to use.. any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: can you give more details about the *'at least 5 posts'*?

Comment: i need to display the latest 5 posts from each month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one possibility is to run all posts through the loop and only output the month once per new month:

```
<?php       
$counter = 0;
$ref_month = '';
$monthly = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1));
if( $monthly->have_posts() ) : while( $monthly->have_posts() ) : $monthly->the_post();

    if( get_the_date('mY') != $ref_month ) { 
        if( $ref_month ) echo "\n".'</ul>';
        echo "\n".'<h6>'.get_the_date('F').'</h6>';
        echo "\n".'<ul>';
        $ref_month = get_the_date('mY');
        $counter = 0;
    }

if( $counter++ < 5 ) echo "\n".'   <li><a href='.get_permalink($post->ID).'>'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a></li>';

endwhile; 
echo "\n".'</ul>';
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: I thought of doing this but was looking for a more 'native' solution.. nothing out of the box that can generate this automatically?

Comment: Here's another response on So: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479176/how-do-i-display-all-months-with-the-5-latest-posts

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more readable version of the solution provided by Michael

```
<?php       
$posts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1));
if ($posts->have_posts()): ?>
<ul id="archives">
    <?php 
    $prev_month = '';
    while ($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post();
    if (get_the_date('F Y') != $prev_month): 
        $prev_month = get_the_date('F Y'); ?>
    <li class="month"><?= $prev_month; ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```